# Bazel build fail for drake schunk driver

Tags: drake

I am trying to build the Schunk drivers from the `RobotLocomotion/drake-schunk-driver` git repository.
When I run `bazel build //...`, the build fails and I get errors for missing dependencies like `gflags` and `glib`.

Is there a list of the required dependencies somewhere?

I am using drake v1.8.0 on Ubuntu Focal and installed it via the apt method if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the question, the repository, https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-schunk-driver, uses Bazel as its primary build (even via CMake, I believe), following the [drake_bazel_external](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/eabc1a36bd7fe1537aadbb559e6af76ed3878d9f/drake_bazel_external) workflow (compiling using Bazel from source).

The above error most likely occurs due to an older / incorrect version of Bazel being installed, and/or other missing Bazel source prerequisites.

Confirm your apt-installed Drake version using `dpkg -s drake-dev`, then ensure you install the source prereqs for that tagged version.

Per the OP question for Ubuntu Focal and Drake v1.8.0, this would look like as follows: 
https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html#mandatory-platform-specific-instructions 
https://drake.mit.edu/ubuntu.html

```bash
git clone -o upstream https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake -b v1.8.0
cd drake
sudo ./setup/ubuntu/install_prereqs.sh
```

EDIT: Submitted PR https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-schunk-driver/pull/9

---

*Additional Note* 
At time of writing (2022-10), the `apt` package for Drake does not appear to install Bazel. 
To inspect w/ installed `apt` package, look at `Depends` section from output of `dpkg -s drake-dev`. 
To inspect w/o installation, you can download the latest nightly debian per https://drake.mit.edu/apt.html#nightly-releases, inspect the control data, and see that the control data does not include `bazel` as a dependency. 
(This could be considered a good thing b/c it might require yet another apt repository.)